# ENV variable in docker environment

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

Hello how can I use env variable in Docker / docker-compose in the most convenient way?
I am working with Django and in local environment I have something like this which works perfect - `stripe.api_key = os.environ.get('stripeAPI')` What should I do to do it in Docker container? When I wrote `docker exec -e stripeAPI=(secret key) <container_id>`I got an error command not found, but when I wrote at the end `echo` or `bash` I get into shell but Stripe does not work.

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/?

Answer (score 0):

If you use docker-compose, you can create `.env` file with `stripeAPI` variable and add this option to `docker-compose` config to your django service:

> env_file:
> `-` "path to your .env"

So `stripeAPI` will be available in your django container